# How to view Django test server errors log?

Tags: django

Tester complains about errors that force to restart django test server several times.However never logged the actual errors from the terminal.

Is there  a way to view a log and to get the errors that forced the server to fail? (I am not able to reproduce error that will force server to fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is default logging mechanism for Django. Configure settings as described in Django documentation, add logging calls to code and you are able to fetch log in files. Please visit this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#configuring-logginghttp://) to learn how to configure logging.